# Restrict downloads on Windows 10

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-10

I am a bit new with Senior IT support and GPOs, so please be patient.

I want to restrict downloads/access to all folders (Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Videos etc.) except Downloads for users using Windows 10, without using roaming profiles or map network drives (if possible). I applied GPOs on my Domain Controller Microsoft Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit).

I tried restricting access to all drives via GPO User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> File Explorer -> "Hide these specified drives in My Computer" and "Prevent access to these specified drives in My Computer", however, naturally, I could not access Downloads that way. Furthermore, even with these 2 GPOs I was able to download a picture on my desktop after I tried a second time and I am not sure why (I got a restriction error the first time, but once I clicked OK and tried downloading again, the windows for where to save appeared and I could download anywhere).

I removed the previous 2 GPOs and tried another GPO Computer Configuration ->  Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> File System and tried adding each folder with only read permission except Download which had write permission (For the Delivery Group "Users" only) - that did not work so I tried setting Deny to Full access making Deny even for Read permissions for User Delivery Group to all folders and drives except Downloads folder which had write permissions again. This time, I had no access to C:\ with the test user account, however, I could still access the rest of the folders even with Deny permissions and also was still able to download files and save them (this time I did not even get a prompt that it is not allowed.)

I read that it is also possible to tweak the Registry Keys to restrict downloads and access, however I am unsure on how to do that and if it will help me.

I hope I summarized things well enough, but if I haven't and missed something, please let me know and I will try to answer/explain better.

PS: I forgot to mention that I have added the Test machine and Test accounts to Security Filtering in Group Policy Management and I have created a test OU and the GPOs were applied and linked only to the test OU. I have removed Authenticated Users as to prevent applying this policy on the whole domain.

Regards,
Stefanie